# Mapping on Glass Surface

Tags: sensors, mapping

Hi i am building a robot that can travel on a transparent/glass surface but i want to map the whole surface. What is the best Solution for a 2D mapping of a transparent surface?

-Is Lidar mapping good enough for this project?

-I think it would also work with a hard-coded algorithm but which sensors are required to detect the edge of a Transparent surface?

Thank You !

[image]

Comment: How big is the area? And your robot? Are the any (static) objects next to your surface?

Comment: Is there something on the glass that needs mapping, or are you just looking for the borders of a flat 2D surface?

Comment: Looking for border of a flat 2D(glass surface). Is it possible to do mapping with a IR sensor?

Answer (score 1):

The surface itself won't help you, so the question is if you have a border of objects next to the surface that your laser can see.

You also don't have to fix your sensor to the robot. You can also mount a laserscanner on the glas surface (e.g. with some suction cups), locate the robot and then send it its position. (Same idea as a ground radar at an airport)

If your robot could drive off the surface, check the approaches used by vacuum robots (which should also not drive down the stairs). Downfacing IR- or Ultrasonic sensors work nicely.

Comment: Is glass not opaque to IR..or am i thinking UV generally? Could one not map the inverse? As in following a path on glass visable to said ir or uv sensor?

Comment: You have to provide a lot more information on the problem. Is this a competition with fixed rules or are you able to change the surface?

Comment: The surface change and there are no fixed rules. I think to do a 2D mapping with grids on the surface would be the best practice but how many IR sensors do i need ? and which mcu?

Comment: But which feature do you want to use?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can apply plaster tape which is non residue to glass on the point of laser and do gmapping and then remove it

Comment: and then you have a map, but no sensor values to locate on it...